# Ajax call and then include a blade section

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a {{!! Form::model!!}} where I am passing a variable $values from the Controller and displaying it inside of the Form select those values. In mine main blade i have 3 additional blades I am including through

```
@if($jobs->open)
            @include('jobs.review.open')
            @endif
```

I am trying to load the data $jobs from controller only when someone clicks , I figured to do some by create an ajax call with onclick event, so i have the data $jobs back. An only now trying to include jobs.review.open blade.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

One common strategy is to put the rendering in the AJAX call.  The server returns a ready-to-go chunk of HTML in its reply, and the JavaScript code simply inserts it into the DOM at the appropriate place with `innerHTML`.  The server uses a blade to prepare the HTML that it then returns.

The initial page HTML that is displayed doesn't include the content, but does include dummy placeholder `<div>`s which mark the places where the HTML will be inserted.

Comment: I will try that! Thank you